# ModelBuilder export/sharing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I was wondering when trying to export a ModelBuilder, is there another way besides exporting it the whole package or a python script?

Because with the ModelBuilder there will be different imagery bands I will be using, I want to share just the builder itself without sharing the input data.

Comment: You could turn it into a tool with parameters.  See https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/create-a-model-tool.htm.  I often went the inelegant route of saving a project with various models in it that pointed to data, and then changed the data input and output paths for each subsequent use, and when done didn't save the changes. to the models or project.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?  Have you tried just providing the TBX file?